# Converting an image from HTTP response into byte array in Grails?

Tags: image, http, servlets, grails, response

I have a Grails action inside a controller. In this action I use:

```
def url = "http://www.somedomain.com/image/test.jpg"
def requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()
def request = requestFactory.createRequest(uri, method)
...
def response = request.execute()
  if(statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
def responseImage = response.body.text
}
```

This returns a jpg image in my response.body.text object. I have no idea how I can handle this image. How can I convert this image to a byte array?

Comment: Please clarify, the question is unclear. Sending a http request to an image seems a bit odd..

Comment: @Marco I updated the question. Do you have any idea what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClientHttpResponse.getBody()` returns an `InputStream`, so you could just do `response.body.bytes` (using the Groovy-JDK [InputStream.getBytes()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#getBytes%28%29) extension) instead of `response.body.text`